# Can anyone resolve my 'cannot access serially reusable package issue'?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Working on below package, when i execute **P_proc3** , I receive error as
**"ORA-06534: Cannot access Serially Reusable package"** Need help in resolving this

I read 
"The SERIALLY_REUSABLE pragma indicates that the package state is needed only for the duration of one call to the server (for example, an OCI call to the database or a stored procedure call through a database link). After this call, the storage for the package variables can be reused, reducing the memory overhead for long-running sessions."

But just understood that this package instance will  not be in buffer memory.

**CODE given below**

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY COG_MIGR_TRNS
as
  PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;

  function get_itr_nm return varchar2
  as
    itr_name varchar2(30);
    cursor c1 is
      select value 
        from params where obj_id =45877; 
  begin
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into itr_name;
    close c1;
    return itr_name;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
  end;

  -----------------------------------

  PROCEDURE P_proc1 
  IS
    v_nm varchar(100);
    cursor c1 is
      select get_iteration_name() 
        from dual;
  BEGIN
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into v_nm;
    close c1;
    <Some more code Here using v_nm>
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE; 
  end;

  ------------------------

  PROCEDURE P_proc2 
  IS
    v_nm varchar(100);
    cursor c1 is
    select get_iteration_name() 
      from dual;
  BEGIN
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into v_nm;
    close c1;
    <Some more code Here using v_nm>
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
  end;

  -------------------
  PROCEDURE P_proc3 
  IS
    v_nm varchar(100);
    cursor c1 is
      select get_iteration_name() 
        from dual;
  BEGIN
    P_Proc1;
    P_Proc2;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RAISE;
  end;
```

Comment: `get_iteration_name()` and  `get_itr_nm()` are the same or not? If they are and you just misstyped the name of the function then the error is because you are trying to reference a function of a serially reusable package in a SQL statement(`select` statement in this case - your `c1` cursor).

Comment: I think if you make the code fetch ALL data from SERIALLY_REUSABLE package in one call, it will work.